# Find $t$ such that (subspace)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For $t\in\mathbb{R}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is given $V_t={\rm span}([t, -1, 2,-1],[1,-1,-1,1])$.

Find all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $V_t={\rm span}([4, -3,  0,1],[1,0, 3,-2])$.

EDIT: Still do not know how to solve the question

Comment: hint: what is span{(t, 0, 0, 0)} for different t?

Comment: a line? do not get thehint, more informations needed

Comment: always a line? What dimension is the space? What dimension is $V_t$?

Comment: no four dimensions has the space, but i do not get how to obtain a solution to the question with the knowkledge of that

Comment: a line has dimension 1 but span{(t, 0, 0, 0)} is not always a line. When is it not? Now think about your $V_t$ - what is its dimension for different t values?

Comment: t will be equal to zero?

Comment: If t = 0 then span{(t, 0,0,0)} will just be be the (0, 0, 0, 0) vector, a 0 dimensional subspace. If t is not 0 then it will be a 1 dimensional subspace. Now think about $V_t$ - what is its dimension?

Comment: Either three or four

Comment: Sorry, I had a completely other (wrong) thing in my head for some reason & wasted your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to solve the equations

\begin{equation}
[4,-3,0,1]=\alpha[t,-1,2,-1]+\beta[1,-1,-1,1]
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
[1,0,3,-2]=\alpha[t,-1,2,-1]+\beta[1,-1,-1,1].
\end{equation}
The solution for $t$ is 2.